# How to protect sensitive data on CircleCi?

Tags: circleci

Where to store sencitive information like signing configs, api keys etc on Cicrle without adding them to git.
Normaly I dont upload such files to git repositories, but I dont see how can I use Circle without them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use private environment variables. This would be loaded into CircleCI via the webapp or API, and then injected into a running build. This way, sensitive information won't have to be stored in your repository.

Here's a doc on Environment Variables in [CircleCI 1.0](https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/environment-variables/) and [CircleCI 2.0](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/env-vars/).

Answer (score 2):

Use environment variable. If you want to use file, encode it as base 64 string https://support.circleci.com/hc/en-us/articles/360003540393-How-to-insert-files-as-environment-variables-with-Base64

> If you need to insert sensitive text-based documents or even small binary files into your project in secret it is possible to insert them as an environment variable by leveraging base64 encoding.

It seems CircleCI does not support sensitive file yet.